# Static assets configuration cannot apply nginx in ingress for PHP

Tags: php, laravel, kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress

I built the php application deployment with using k8s Ingress. I can access the `index.php` also I can access to the panel side, the php exectuion in PHP-FPM is also ok but I couln't react to the static assets. My server snippet that I have applied to the Ingress is working in docker-compose in my local with nginx but not working in Ingress. I can see the requests logs to the fpm from the Ingress but result is always 404 for like these below links;

```
https://[baseuri]/demo/plugins // 200 ok because its basic index.php

https://[baseuri]/themes/demo/assets/vendor/jquery.js // 404
```

At the moment, I could saw requests to the fpm until changed the configuration. Now I couldn't reach to the fpm. Requests will interrupt immediately from Ingress with status 404.

I have read a lot of post/documentation and I tried bunch of different configurations but I couldn't reach 200. I don't want to use nginx container in my fpm pod, I think that is not the best practice. Ingress already supported that behaviour before with this development https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/2982

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: ingress-cm
data:
  SCRIPT_FILENAME: "/var/www/index.php"
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "1800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "1800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/fastcgi_send_timeout: "1800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/fastcgi_read_timeout: "1800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "FCGI"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/fastcgi-index: "index.php"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/fastcgi-params-configmap: "ingress-cm"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      ...
      location ~ ^/themes/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }
      location ~ ^/themes/.*/bundles { try_files $uri 404; }
      location ~ ^/themes/.*/resources { try_files $uri 404; }
  name: app-ingress
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - {url}
      secretName: letsencrypt
  rules:
    - host: {url}
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: app-service
                port:
                  number: 9000 
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app
  labels:
    app: app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: {reg}
      containers:
      - name: app
        image: {image}
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-service
  labels:
    run: app-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9000
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: app
```